# Integration theory. Why $F$ is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be an  integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e.,  $ \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \ dx <\infty $.

And let $F(u)=\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \sin(ux)\ dx$ where $u \in \mathbb{R}$ and then, $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}.$

Suppose $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+|x|)|f(x)| dx < \infty.$

Then, prove that $F$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to prove by considering $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to u_0} \dfrac{F(u)-F(u_0)}{u-u_0}$ but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What was the problem with that approach? It actually works very well, using Dominated Convergence.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for your advice. I tried calculate $\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{F(a+h)-F(a)}{h}$ by using Dominated Convergence Theorem and this seems to work…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more robust approach is to utilize the fundamental theorem of calculus. To this end, define

$$ G(u) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x) \cos(ux) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Then by the assumption $G(\cdot)$ is well-defined. Moreover, $G(\cdot)$ is continuous. Indeed, for any $u \in \mathbb{R}$ and for any sequence $(u_k)$ converging to $u$, the estimate

$$ \left| x f(x) \cos(u_k x) \right| \leq |x| |f(x)| $$

shows that we can invoke the dominated convergence to get

$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} G(u_k) = G(u). $$

This shows that $G(\cdot)$ is continuous as claimed. Moreover, by the Fubini's Theorem,

$$ \int_{a}^{b} G(u) \, \mathrm{d}u
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{a}^{b}  x f(x) \cos(ux) \, \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)(\sin(bx) - \sin (ax)) \, \mathrm{d}x
= F(b) - F(a). $$

So by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $F'(u) = G(u)$.

Comment: @Sangchul_Lee So, is the supposition $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+|x|)|f(x)| dx < \infty$ unnecessary ?

Comment: @Luca, It's actually the opposite. That condition is critically used in the proof, to ensure the well-definedness of $F$ and $G$, continuity of $G$, and the applicability of the Fubini's theorem. The condition $\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x<\infty$ alone can only ensure the well-definedness of $F$, so the second assumption does play a key role in the proof.